# Declaring Const With Curly Braces in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm just getting started with React Native and getting used to JSX syntax. Is that what I'm talking about? Or am I talking about TypeScript? Or... ES6? Anyway...

I've seen this:

```
const { foo } = this.props;
```

Inside a class function. What is the purpose of the curly braces and what's the difference between using them and not using them?

Comment: its called [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 42):

It is [destructuring assignment](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#destructuring).

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
>   objects, into distinct variables.

Example (ES6):

```
var person = {firstname: 'john', lastname: 'doe'};

const firstname = person.firstname;
const lastname = person.lastname;

// same as this
const { firstname, lastname } = person;
```

You can find more info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

EDIT: also for developers familiar with Python language it can be interesting to compare with Python unpacking syntax.
Python2.7:

```
>>> _tuple = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a, b, c = _tuple
>>> print(a, b, c)
(1, 2, 3)
```

With new feature of Python3, like [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) you can also do following:

```
>>> _range = range(5)
>>> a, *b, c = _range
>>> print(a, b, c)
0 [1, 2, 3] 4
```

Examples are added, because knowing already similar approach from other languages you can grasp JS idea more quicker.

Comment: Looks like it could be right to me, although I guess by "app" you meant "person"? And I guess "first_name" and "last_name" shouldn't have underscores. But I get what you mean!

Comment: @Varrick , yes, typos. underscores are there not to get error about same variable names. updated example.

Comment: It makes sense when you're declaring more-than-1 variable like this:

`const { firstname, lastname } = person;`

But what relevance does it have with only 1 variable, like this:
`const { new_person } = person;`

Comment: What is Python doing here?

Comment: @robinmetral "Examples are added, because knowing already similar approach from other languages you can grasp JS idea more quicker."

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is destructuring assignment feature of ECMASCRIPT 6

For Example :

```
const { createElement } = React
const { render } = ReactDOM

const title = createElement('h1', {id: 'title', className: 'header'}, 'Hello World')

render(title, document.getElementById('react-container'))
```

here ^

```
React == { 
  cloneElement  : function(){ ... },
  createElement : function(){ ... },
  createFactory : function(){ ... }, 
... }
```